# Query latest entry filter by criterion

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to output the latest entries, filtered by a specific criterion. I have this model :

```
class Task(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Activation")
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=1, default=2)
    mode = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    category = models.ForeignKey(TaskCategory, verbose_name="Catégorie")
    city = models.ForeignKey(AppCity, verbose_name="Ville")
    skill = models.ManyToManyField(SkillKind, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Compétence requise")
```

I want to get the fifth latest entry for each `city`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want the 5 latest or the fifth from last?

Comment: I want 5 latest for each city (sorry for my english ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no date/datetime field and no explicit ordering so I'm not sure what "latest" means in this context, but anyway: assuming the default ordering is ok for you or you set it in your queryset:

```
for city in AppCity.objects.all():
    print city.task_set.reverse()[:5]
```

Comment: Yes I have a datetime field but I removed it to my question. I understand your logic, I will stock the result of each city in a dictionary. Merci ;)